# Graph API create groups and teams from SPFx webpart with elevated privileges

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, spfx, sharepointframework

I have a SPFx webpart which is a form for users to submit requests which will run the group and teams provisioning code.

The code works fine when the user is logged in as a 'Global Admin', but when a normal user with minimum permission levels uses the form, the provisioning is not allowed and is faced with these errors:

Creating group is not allowed:
[Tenant admin has not enabled Unified group creation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8V9d.png)

Creating teams is not allowed:
[Teams disabled in user license admin error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCdF9.png)

Is there a way to run the code regardless of the user context? or any ways to elevate the privilege of the webpart or block of code with admin permissions?

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial
You will need to specify that specific api permissions your application needs.
basically starting from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial

specifically, the graph api permissions that you will need is at least Group.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All in order to create a team.

Hopefully this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to run the code regardless of the user context?

Yes. You could implement [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) to use Application permission to create the resources. It will allow you to create a group without a user.

You can also check with your admin if the ability of creation Groups for users has been disabled. See [Manage who can create Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/create-groups/manage-creation-of-groups?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fManage-who-can-create-Office-365-Groups-4c46c8cb-17d0-44b5-9776-005fced8e618&view=o365-worldwide).

And it's strongly recommended to check if the Teams license is assigned to the user.